# Cython: dimensions is not a member of 'tagPyArrayObject'

Tags: cython

I implemented a pure Python code in object-oriented style. In some of the methods there are time intensive loops, which I hope to speed up by cythonizing the code.

I am using a lot of numpy arrays and struggle with converting classes into Cython extension types.

Here I declare two numpy arrays 'verteces' and 'norms' as attributes:

import numpy as np
    cimport numpy as np

```python
cdef class Geometry(object):

    cdef:
        np.ndarray verteces
        np.ndarray norms

    def __init__(self, config):
        """ Initialization"""
        self.config         = config

        self.verteces       = np.empty([1,3,3],dtype=np.float32)
        self.norms          = np.empty(3,dtype=np.float32)
```

During runtime the actual size of the arrays will be defined. This happens when calling the `Geometry.load()` method of the same class. The method opens an STL-file and loops over the triangle entries.

Finally I want to determine the intersection points of the triangles and a ray. In the respective method I use the following declarations.

```python
cdef void hit(self, object photon):
    """ Ray-triangle intersection according to Moeller and Trumbore algorithm """

    cdef:
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] verteces    = self.verteces         # nx3x3
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] norms       = self.norms
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] ph_dir      = photon.direction
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] ph_origin   = photon.origin

        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] v0, v1, v2, vec1, vec2, trsc, norm, v, p_inter

        float a, b, par, q, q0, q1, s0, s1

        int i_tri
```

When I try to compile this code I get the following error message:

```python
'dimensions' is not a member of 'tagPyArrayObject'
```

[image: error]

I am not very familiar cython programming, but maybe the error is do to the fact that I have to initialize an array of fixed size in a C-extension type? The size of the array is, however, unkown until the STL-file is read.

Comment: Why not take the original Moeller Trumbore algorithm (C++, http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/personal/tomas_akenine-moller/raytri/raytri.c) and call it from Cython, rather than reimplementing it in a language that will make it run hundredfold slower. Or did I misunderstood and is that what you're planning. I've used the original and it works fine. Only you'll have to build in some special checks for rays hitting the vertices or edges of triangles.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is related to your problem, but I've got the same identical error message when specifying the "NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" macro in my setup.py file.

```
extension_module = Extension(
    'yourfilename',
    sources=["yourfilename.pyx],
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    define_macros=[("NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API", "NPY_1_7_API_VERSION")],
)
```

With this macro, a simple `npmatrix.shape[0]` numpy function is compiled as:

```
/* "yourfilename.pyx":35
 * 
 *     cpdef int vcount(self):
 *         return self.npmatrix.shape[0]
 * 
 */
  __pyx_r = (__pyx_v_self->npmatrix->dimensions[0]);
```

which causes the error. Just removing the macro resolved this error to me.